# How to configure Stub proxy to consume SOAP service javax ws

Tags: apache, soap, soap-client, javax

I am pushing the data from my application to other application through soap service. I have imported the wsdl and able to push the data to application too.

My problem is, I always dependent on other application to check push data in request and wait for response. It is consuming my development time lot.
Is there any way to configure the proxy or stub kind of thing and get response from proxy item in dev environment instead of keep on hitting third party application?

Answer (score 0):

It has simple solution. Just create your own Mock service and deploy it in your local dev environment Tomcat/eclipse-embedded-tomcat(I'm here assuming that you are using Java as you have tagged as Javax).

When you generate soap client from WSDL, you could also generate and server Interface and its implementation, put a dummy implementation and deploy it locally.

Refer link http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html to get more details.
use $wsdl2java command with **-server** and **-impl** options.

```
wsdl2java - takes a WSDL document and generates fully annotated Java code from which to implement a service.
```